# Python: Dynamic attribute name generation without exec() or eval()

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm trying to dynamically create buttons at runtime with PyQT4.7

However, this being my first python program I'm not sure how to get the functionality I want.

I would like to be able to substitute a text string for an attribute name:

i.e.

```
for each in xrange(4):
    myname = "tab1_button%s" % each  #tab1_button0, tab1_button1, tab1_button2

    #self.ui.tab1_button0 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.ui.tab) <--normal code to create a named button
     setattr(self.ui,myname,QtGui.QPushButton(self.ui.tab)) #rewrite of line above to dynamicly generate a button

#here's where I get stuck. this code isn't valid, but it shows what i want to do
     self.ui.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ui.%s) % myname
#I need to have %s be tab1_button1, tab1_button2, etc. I know the % is for string substituion but how can I substitute the dynamically generated attribute name into that statement?
```

I assume there's a basica language construct I'm missing that allows this. Since it's my first program, please take it easy on me ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I interpreted this correctly, I think what you want is this:

`self.ui.gridLayout.addWidget(getattr(self.ui,myname))`

Give that a go.  In Python the following two statements are functionally equivalent (from the link below):

```
value = obj.attribute
value = getattr(obj, "attribute-name")
```

For extra context:

http://effbot.org/zone/python-getattr.htm

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the button to a variable so you can both set the attribute and add the widget.

```
for i in range(4):
    name = 'button%d' % i
    button = QtGui.QPushButton(...)
    setattr(self, name, button)
    self.ui.gridLayout.addWidget(button)
```

Personally I would add the buttons to a list instead of giving them different names.

Comment: in this scenario the buttons are getting numerically ordered names, but in the program i'm writing, their entire names will be pulled from a dictionary, so I'm not sure how I'd keep track of them without intelligent names with your example

Comment: Store the buttons in a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might benefit from knowledge of lists (commonly called arrays in other languages)

```
self.buttons = [None, None, None, None]
for each in xrange(4):
     self.buttons[each] = QtGui.QPushButton(self.ui.tab)
     self.ui.gridLayout.addWidget(self.buttons[each])
```

For a tutorial on Python lists:
http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm